# a function that prints the second word of any sentence i have a probleme when a string is like "ghanou djellal"it returns nothing

Tags: python

```
    # Strip function remove the whitespaces from the start and the end of the string.
a = str(input("Enter Your String : ").strip())
```

> the function that returns the second element

```
def second_word(a):
    b = 0
    c = a.split(" ")
    while b < len(c):
        if c[b] == "" and c[b+1] != "":
            print(f" Your Second Word Is :{c[b+1]}")
            break
        b += 1
second_word(a)
```

Comment: I see you are using `c = a.split(" ")` to process the string, and then trying to handle any `''` in the result. If you read the documentation for `.split`, you should see a much easier way.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it much easier if you use the split() methode and print the second element (index 1) of the list.

```
def secondword(sentence):
    listofwords = sentence.split(" ")
    return listofwords[1]

print(secondword("My name is"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition `c[b] == ""` will never hold, unless the original string is `""`.

`c` is a list. In order to access its second element you would do `c[1]`.

```
def second_word(a):
    c = a.split(" ")
    print(f" Your Second Word Is :{c[1]}")

second_word(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you simply do:

```
def second_word(a):
    return a.split()[1]
```

If you want to write a function along the logic you proposed (well - this is not advised - but just to articulate on what you tried to do):

```
def second_word(a):
    start = 0
    for i, l in enumerate(a):
        if l == " ":
            if start == 0:
                start = i
            else:
                print("You second word is: " + a[start:i].strip())
                break
```